# extra subset of xml input in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I need an xslt file to transform the input xml. It needs to output the employee's name when their age is over 40. Each record needs a comma at the end, and the last record needs a semi-colon.

Input

```
<employees>
    <employee>
        <name>Bill Jordan</name>
        <age>40</age>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name>Larry Bird</name>
        <age>42</age>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name>Joe King</name>
        <age>25</age>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name>John Smith</name>
        <age>45</age>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name>Kathy Bush</name>
        <age>31</age>
    </employee>
</employees>
```

Output

Bill Jordan,

Larry Bird,

John Smith;

Comment: "*I need an xslt file*" is not a question. Where exactly are stuck with this (trivial) task?

Answer (score 0):

try out this code

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <good>
    <xsl:variable name="data" select="employees//employee[./age&gt;=40]"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="$data">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="count($data)!=position()">
            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
            <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </good>
  </xsl:template>
```